# Html template-tag: Prevent <image> becomes <img>

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the original text from a template. I try with innerHTML, but "image" becomes "img".

```js
let tplText = document.getElementById("idTplTest").innerHTML;
console.log('tplText: ' + tplText);
console.log('<image> becomes <img> :(');
```

```html
<template id="idTplTest">
        <image xlink:href="imgs/pp.jpg" height="500" width="1400" />
</template>
```

How can i get the original text?

Comment: `<image>` is for SVGs, so if you place your `<image>` inside `<svg>` this shouldn't happen (based on a quick test).

Comment: Still have problems... Is there no way to get the original untouched text inside the template?

Answer (score 0):

Thx chriskirknielsen!

```js
let tplText = document.getElementById("idTplTest").innerHTML;
console.log('tplText: ' + tplText);
console.log('<image> is still <image> :)');

let tplTextImg = document.getElementById("idTplTest").content.firstElementChild.innerHTML;
console.log('And only the image-tag: ' + tplTextImg);
```

```html
<template id="idTplTest">
  <svg>
        <image id="idTplImg" xlink:href="imgs/pp.jpg" height="500" width="1400" />
  </svg>
</template>
```